# Excel COUNTIF by Month

Tags: excel, formula, countif

a noobie Excel question.

I have a sample spreadsheet as below:

[image]

[image]

As you can see I can calculate how many times the unique `Traders` have appeared by using `COUNTIF`. However, I can't figure out how count them by month. For example, `Tailwind Traders Alpha $` has appeared **FOUR** times for the month of **November**.

I just can't figure out the formula and have no idea how to combine formulas.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: May be `PRODUCTIF()` ?

Comment: The cool way is, indeed, with a complex formula that you need to handle properly. But another option would be using PivotTables to get what you want. You could group your data by month and count how many `Traders` you got and more stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `C16` you could put formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*alpha $*",$A$2:$A$11)))*(MONTH($B$2:$B$11)=MONTH(C$15))*(YEAR($B$2:$B$11)=YEAR(C$15)))
```

You could also use `COUNTIFS()`

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$11,">="&C$15,$B$2:$B$11,"<"&EDATE(C$15,1),$A$2:$A$11,"*alpha*")
```

To make it more dynamic, you should replace your value in `A16` with `Alpha $` and then use this formula in `C16`:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$11,">="&C$15,$B$2:$B$11,"<"&EDATE(C$15,1),$A$2:$A$11,"*"&$A16)
```

Drag down and right...

[image]

Drag right.

Comment: Thank you sir, however what about `C17` ? Where it does not contain `Alpha $`

Comment: @envyM6, for second formula in cell `C17` you need to swap `"*alpha*"` with `"<>*alpha*"` just like you did in your `COUNTIF()`